# methods with variable names and alias methods

Tags: javascript

I've moved this question from Code Review  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95205/methods-with-variable-names-and-alias-methods

**Please read the code review answers and comments**

I'm writing a javascript code that runs functions depending on a variable.
Let's assume that there are two domains called (example.com and foo.com), "example.com" has subdomains (a.example.com and b.example.com) and the subdomains have another main domain (www.a.com and www.b.com) what i want to do is run a function based on a domain variable, to do so i created an object and put the methods of each domain in it so i can call it by a variable name and i also wrote "alias functions" for the subdomains and their maindomains (because example.com function apply to it's subdomains)

so this is the code:

```
var subdomains = {
example_com:function(){
    // do stuff related to example.com and it's subdomains (a.example.com and b.exmple.com)
    // and their main domains (www.a.com and www.b.com).
},
www_foo_com:function(){
    // do stuff related to www.foo.com
},
// alias to call example_com() when any of it's subdomains (a.example.com and b.exmple.com)
// or their main domain (www.a.com and www.b.com).
a_example_com:function(){
    // alias to a.example.com
    this.example_com();
},
b_example_com:function(){
    // alias to b.example.com
    this.example_com();
},
www_a_com:function(){
    // alias to www.a.com
    this.example_com();
},
www_b_com:function(){
    // alias to www.b.com
    this.example_com();
}
};
// now i can call the function depending on the domain variiable

var domain = "a.example.com"; //  or it can be b.example.com, www.a.com, www.b.com, www.foo.com

var func_name = domain.replace(/\./g,"_"); // Results: a_example_com

var run = subdomains[func_name](); // run the function related to the domain or subdomain
```

The code works fine and do what expected but i was hoping anothor way that can save me time and effort to write alias functions to all the subdomains because there are domains that have 20 subdomains ! imagine writing 20 alias functions for the domains and for their main domains (40 functions)

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is the concept of inheritance? In javaScript, there is the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for that. Maybe have a look and see if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for a better Regex to get the function you want.
For example let `www.example.com xyz.example.com` both return `example`:

`var func_name = domain.replace(/.*\.([a-z]+)\.com/,"$1");  // only for .com TLDs`